# return 1970-01-01 date with session date php

Tags: php

Hi Can everyone help me pls? The date return 1970-01-01.
Below are the codes, not sure where is goes wrong

```
$ssdate = str_replace("/","-",$_REQUEST['{$_SESSION['sdate']}']);
          $ssdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($ssdate));
          echo $ssdate;
```

have to changed to

```
$ssdate = str_replace("/","-",$_SESSION['sdate']);
           $ssdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($ssdate));
         echo $ssdate;
```

still same issue.

Comment: This code will probably throw a syntax error, because the `'` won't parse the session variable correctly.

Comment: Tested the code above and, as said above, it CAN'T work, because it throws a syntax error. The correct syntax is either: `$ssdate = str_replace("/","-",$_REQUEST[$_SESSION['sdate']]);` or `$ssdate = str_replace("/","-",$_REQUEST["{$_SESSION['sdate']}"]);`. Besides, even with the correct syntax, we have no way to know if you have passed the variable 'sdate' correctly, and that's probably why it says 1970-01-01. Where is it coming from? 1970-01-01 is thrown when strtotime($ssdate) is either null or empty. Try to echo $_SESSION['sdate']

Comment: Hi it is coming from my session sdate

Comment: try to echo it then, it must be either null or empty. Also, try to reset your session and execute the code again with that variable set, being sure at the 100% that it has been set.

Comment: it throw 1970-01-01. not sure is it my format of coding is wrong.

Comment: what if i change the session sdate to variable. will it work?

Comment: As long as the $ssdate variable is correct it will. In any case, strtotime will try to guess what the date format is, you don't need to explicity replace / with - . parsing 2015/03/02 is the exact same as 2015-03-02. In any case the $ssdate NEEDS to be correct, and since it is coming from $_SESSION['sdate'] you need to ensure that $_SESSION['sdate'] has been set and exists and is not null or empty. `date("Y-m-d", null); `returns 1970-01-01, exactly like `date("Y-m-d", false);` So yes, fixing the sdate will fix everything.

Comment: hi thanks briosheje, i logout the session and it works!

Comment: you're welcome! don't forget to parse the strings correctly, else nothing will work ;).